# Combining position estimates to enhance user localization

Tags: localization

I have several estimated positions for an object. These positions come from several sensors.

I would like to know if it is possible to combine these different positions into a single position. If yes how to do it?

Comment: sure it is – *sensor fusion*. "How to do it" is a bit of an overly broad question – "by combining them sensibly" is the correct answer there, but what that means depends on your sensors, what kind of data they deliver, what the statistical properties of the error are and what the purpose of all this is! Maybe extend your question with much more information about the system as a whole, and the components.

Comment: For example, if they all have the same error statistics with their individually unbiased location estimators, then a simple average might be good. If you have some mathematical model that says "if four estimates are close by, and one is far away, that one is in error and should be ignored", then doing an average would be bad, wouldn't it? Many localization methods however give you some kind of confidence alongside with the position estimate, so that a weighted averaging makes sense. Often, you have external data (e.g. a map that tells you where lakes are, and hence where your car can't be).

Comment: An additional issue with multiple sensors is the handling of time synchronization. Are the objects you're measuring moving or stationary?

Comment: @MarcusMüller $^*$ **shouldn't** be.